# designing class structures

Tags: python, class, constructor, structure

I am a complete beginner in object oriented programming and I have this weird homework assignment.

Basically it's about Santa, how he is in some city and goes from house to house and gives gifts to people.

The first part of my homework goes like this:

Write a class `City`.

- Constructor has no arguments. What it does, is up to you: it has to prepare the terrain for other methods.
- Method `gift(x, y)` records that the house at coordinates `(x, y)` received a gift
- Method `was_gifted(x, y)` returns `True` if the house at `(x, y)` got a gift; `False` otherwise.
- Method `all_gifted()` returns a set of coordinates of all houses that got gifts.

So far I have this (and don't know if it's correct):

```
class City:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coordinates = set()

    def gift(self, x, y):
        self.coordinates.add((x, y))

    def was_gifted(self, x, y):
        if (x, y) in self.coordinates:
            return True

    def all_gifted(self):
        self.coordinates
```

The second part of my homework goes like this:

Write a class `Santa`.

- Constructor has an argument that represents the city in which Santa Claus will distribute gifts. In the beginning, he stands at coordinates `(0, 0)`.
- Method `move(c)` gets the character `"v"`, `"^"`, `"<"` or `">"` and moves Santa Claus one field down, up, left or right. Coordinate `y` increases upwards this time; i.e. `"^"` increases it by one and `"v"` decreases it.
- Method `moves(path)` gets a string of such characters and moves Santa Claus accordingly.
- Method `gift()` gives a gift to the house at the current Santa Claus' coordinates.  Note that `gift` has no arguments (except for `self`).

Besides that, write class`RapidSanta`, which is derived from `Santa`. Its constructor gets a `city` and `speed`. `RapidSanta` differs from the ordinary one in that it does not move by single fields but with the `speed` we set in the constructor.

Can someone please help me because I don't even know how and where to start. And if someone knows a similar "problem", please link or post on the forum. I want to master this but frankly I am NOT a programming genius. Thank you for all your help in advance. Below are the tests which my assignment must pass.

```
import unittest

class TestCity(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_City(self):
        a = City()
        b = City()

        self.assertSetEqual(a.all_gifted(), set())
        self.assertSetEqual(b.all_gifted(), set())
        self.assertFalse(a.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertFalse(b.is_gifted(1, 3))

        a.gift(1, 3)
        self.assertSetEqual(a.all_gifted(), {(1, 3)})
        self.assertSetEqual(b.all_gifted(), set())
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertFalse(b.is_gifted(1, 3))

        a.gift(1, 3)
        self.assertSetEqual(a.all_gifted(), {(1, 3)})
        self.assertSetEqual(b.all_gifted(), set())
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertFalse(a.is_gifted(-2, -3))
        self.assertFalse(b.is_gifted(1, 3))

        a.gift(-2, -3)
        self.assertSetEqual(a.all_gifted(), {(1, 3), (-2, -3)})
        self.assertSetEqual(b.all_gifted(), set())
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(-2, -3))
        self.assertFalse(b.is_gifted(1, 3))

        b.gift(0, 0)
        self.assertSetEqual(a.all_gifted(), {(1, 3), (-2, -3)})
        self.assertSetEqual(b.all_gifted(), {(0, 0)})
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertTrue(a.is_gifted(-2, -3))
        self.assertFalse(b.is_gifted(1, 3))
        self.assertTrue(b.is_gifted(0, 0))
        self.assertFalse(a.is_gifted(0, 0))


class TestSanta(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_gift(self):
        m = City()
        n = City()
        b = Santa(m)
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0)})
        self.assertSetEqual(n.all_gifted(), set())

    def test_move(self):
        m = City()
        n = City()
        b = Santa(m)
        c = Santa(m)
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0)})
        self.assertSetEqual(n.all_gifted(), set())
        b.move("^")
        b.move("<")
        b.move("<")
        b.gift()
        b.move("v")
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1)})
        self.assertSetEqual(n.all_gifted(), set())
        c.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1)})
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1), (-2, 0)})
        b.move(">")
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1), (-2, 0)})
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1), (-2, 0), (-1, 0)})
        c.move("v")
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1), (-2, 0), (-1, 0)})
        c.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (-2, 1), (-2, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1)})
        self.assertSetEqual(n.all_gifted(), set())


    def test_moves(self):
        m = City()
        b = Santa(m)
        b.moves("v<<^^^>>>>>")
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(3, 2)})

        cc = ""
        def p(c):
            nonlocal cc
            cc += c
        b.move = p
        b.moves("v<<^^^>>>>>")
        self.assertEqual(
            cc, "v<<^^^>>>>>",
            "Write a method `moves` so that it will use method `move`")

    def test_rapid_Santa(self):
        m = City()
        b = RapidSanta(m, 2)
        c = RapidSanta(m, 3)
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0)})
        b.move("^")
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (0, 2)})
        b.move("<")
        b.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (0, 2), (-2, 2)})
        c.move("<")
        c.gift()
        self.assertSetEqual(m.all_gifted(), {(0, 0), (0, 2), (-2, 2), (-3, 0)})

    def test_methods(self):
        self.assertIs(RapidSanta.moves, Santa.moves,
                      "RapidSanta has to inherit method moves")
        self.assertIs(RapidSanta.gift, Santa.gift,
                      "RapidSanta has to inherit method gift")
```

Comment: I think this question is a little too broad, can you narrow it down? What's the problem, Python OOP or the task? Personally, I think "What it does, is up to you: it has to prepare the terrain for other methods." is just a horrible exercise when you start out with OOP. The task itself should be clearer. If I were you I would try to decompose it into subtasks that can be solved on their own and ask several more specific questions about those, as the full exercise is rather lengthy and few people will read it all. It might be helpful to sketch out a basic class diagram before you proceed coding.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your `City` class (nb : assuming python 2.x - no need to inherit from `object` in python 3.x)

```
class City(object):   
    def __init__(self):
        self.coordinates = set()

    def gift(self, x, y):
        self.coordinates.add((x, y))

    def was_gifted(self, x, y):
        return (x, y) in self.coordinates

    def all_gifted(self):
        return self.coordinates
```

The specs for the `Santa` class are quite clear as far as I'm concerned. Your class will need a `city` (instance of `City`) and `coords` instance attributes, the first one being passed as argument, the second defaulting to `(0, 0)`.

The `move(self, c)` method will update `self.coords` according to the value of character `c` - ie assuming `(0, 0)` as current coords, `santa.move('^')` should update `self.coords` to `(0, 1)`, - and the `moves(self, moves)` method just iterate over `moves` and call `self.move(c)` for each character in `moves`.

The `gift(self)` method merely calls `self.city.gift()` with the current coords (really a one-liner).

wrt/ `FastSanta`, once you have `Santa` working it's only a matter of overriding `move()` so that coords are updated by more than one unit...

I give you a start with `Santa` 's initializer, then you should be able to try and implement the other methods - and post a more focused question if you have a problem:

```
class Santa(object):
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city
        self.coords = (0, 0)
```

Edit : fixes on the updated OP code:

```
class Santa(City):
```

Why make it a subclass of `City` ??? Is Santa Claus a city ??? Obviously not... You want `class Santa(object):` (python 2.x) or just `class Santa:` (python 3.x)

```
    def __init__(self, City):
        self.city = City
```

Naming conventions : use `CapNames` for classes and `all_lower` for instances. Here, the second argument is expected to be a `City` *instance*, so it should be:

```
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city
```

(snip)

```
    def gift(self):
        self.city.gift
```

This will lookup the name "gift" on `self.city`  - which should yield a `method` object -, discard the method object, and return `None`.  What you want here is to **call** the city's `gift` method, passing it the required `x` and `y` arguments.

To answer your other questions (in the code or in the comments below):

`(x, y) in self.coordinates` is a boolean expression, which will be eval'd (replaced by it effective value) before executing the `return` statement. So
     return

is functionnaly the exact same thing as

```
 if <some-boolean-expression>:
     return True
 else:
     return False
```

but in way less verbose way.

wrt/ `FastSanta` it's actually quite easy, you just need to replace the default 'movement' value `1` used in `Santa.move()` by a value that is passed to `FastSanta`'s constructor.

As a last note : the unittests you were provided are not only meant as a way to validate your code, they also give you quite a few clues about the expected behaviour and even implementation, and even let you test different implementations (like the verbose and non verbose implementations of `was_gifted()`) and find out by yourself if they yield the same results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using python 3.4.3 Does this look ok? I haven't run a program through test just yet. First I want be sure that what I'm writing is actually correct.

I would also like to ask you what's with that was_gifted(self, x, y) function you changed? Will it return True or False or anything else?

And I don't know what to do with Class FastSanta. I have tried a couple of options but none of them seemed ok.

I'm sorry if i sound like complete noob but in school i don't get any good explanation of how things work. Just some useless theory.

Comment: cd my edited answer. wrt/ |=`was_gifted()`, you could try out by yourself, Python as an interactive shell that make it easy to try out code.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this things work. First I had to correct self.coords = (0, 0) to [0, 0] beacuse you cant change tuples. The second problem I have is the test say that there is no city in Santa class. I don't know why. FastSanta is still a mistery to me. The only thing that work is class City.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. First of all I' m using python 3.4.3.

I corrected this program like this:

```
class City:

def __init__(self):
    self.coordinates = set()

def gift(self, x, y):
    self.coordinates.add((x, y))

def was_gifted(self, x, y):
    return (x, y) in self.coordinates # Does this return True or False?????

def all_gifted(self):
    return self.coordinates


class Santa(City):

def __init__(self, City):
    self.city = City
    self.coords = (0, 0)

def move(self, c):
    if c == "^":
        self.coords[1] -= 1
    elif c == "ˇ":
        self.coords[1] += 1
    elif c == "<":
        self.coords[0] -= 1
    elif c == ">":
        self.coords[0] += 1

def moves(self, path):
    for i in path:
        self.move(i)

def gift(self):
    self.city.gift

class FastSanta:
?????????????
```

Does this look ok? I haven't run a program through test just yet. First I want be sure that what I'm writing is actually correct.

I would also like to ask you what's with that was_gifted(self, x, y) function you changed? Will it return True or False or anything else?

And I don't know what to do with Class FastSanta. I have tried a couple of options but none of them seemed ok.

I'm sorry if i sound like complete noob but in school i don't get any good explanation of how things work. Just some useless theory.

Comment: FYI, this isn't a forum-like site with a cascade of posts. Each post is supposed to be an answer to the original question at the top. If you have further inquiries about a specific answer, leave a comment under said answer. Any general statements/clarifications/additions/etc you want to make, edit the question at the top.

Comment: Oo I'm sorry i didn't know. I just joined here so i'm not familiar of how things work.